# Big dropdown when clicked on Select box

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Please help me out...

Let me explain what I want?

When we click on select tag we get dropdown, but with single columns. I am looking for such a select tag which will open a very big screen on click & will display multiple columns.

For example if you will visit http://www.ticketplease.com/ & click on select movies then a big dropdown is opened.

I actually don't know how to proceed further. Is there any online select box generator website?

Please help me.

Comment: if you inspect the 'select movies' you will notice that is not a select tag but a customized drop down menu

Comment: you need to retrieve data rows from the database and display in a div on select input change. Till den check this http://jsfiddle.net/Animeshjain/5NRPW/

Comment: yes buddy you are right , after inspecting it show's that they have not used select tag.. but they have customized it using css & javascript.... am i right?

Comment: Ya exactly you can see they are calling ShowSelection(); and ShowScheduleDates(); functions onclick. And these functions consists the data to be displayed in the pop up css green box.